# Do i have to keep my laptop on while downloading Windows 10 Update, can i continue later from when i stopped

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I Already Reserved windows 10, and the automatic download failed after 84%. This i faced Thrice, so now i don't want to leave my laptop on overnight. Do i have to restart the update download (provided by windows automatic update) when i shutdown my laptop or it will continue further or not. 
PS- Currently i have windows 7 home Premium 64-bit OS(original copy)with 64 bit processor and i live in India.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's so magic about 84%, but it seems a lot of people have been stuck at the same point.

I'd try getting the [Media Creation Tool](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-10/media-creation-tool-install) instead & set up your installer on a USB stick [needs 8GB]
That way, you've separated any download issue from any potential install issue & at least have the full installer to hand.

The tool itself is a small download. When run, it will ask you if you want to 'Upgrade this PC' or 'Create installation media for another PC'.
This second option allows you to download the OS independently of the upgrade process. The tool will download & create a removable device that can either be booted from, or used just to initiate the install from the setup.exe on an already-running existing OS.

If you want/need the free upgrade, don't boot from the USB, just boot to Windows normally, then run the Setup.exe from the stick.
This way you get your free upgrade. When you reach the point at which it asks you for a Windows 10 key, hit *skip* & it will authenticate behind the scenes as a valid upgrade.

If you have a valid Windows 10 key, you can either upgrade or clean install, & enter the valid key when it asks.

Comment: Will i get the windows 10 serial key so later i don't have any problem. And also will you please elaborate some setting up INSTALLER ON USB

Comment: I'd still be inclined to go through the upgrade path - then a) you've got a spare key just in case & b) you won't have the Windows requires activation overlay in the bottom right-hand corner nagging you every moment of your life... even over a fullscreen app/movie etc... until you do get a key, or c) hit the point, as I did with one clean install [which I had to reset & do again] where you cannot get past the key screen *without* a valid WIn10 key.

Comment: I have valid windows 7 key, so can i get the key of windows 10 in any way.  For some reason if i have to format my laptop completely and install windows 10, how will i keep it Original.

Comment: Once you've done an upgrade from a valid Win7 or 8.1 OS, the key is then 'known' to belong to that machine & you can clean install 10 later, or do a reset without issue. If you start from a clean install & *not* upgrade, an actual Win 10 key is needed & you lose the free upgrade.

Comment: After the upgrade do i need to install all drivers cd  that came with my laptop

Comment: After an upgrade [as opposed to a clean install], all drivers will still be in place - some may need updating to accommodate Win10 specifically, the rest should be OK.